# Evaluation stops without output or error when using Nested Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am trying to evaluate a max max min problem. The code is as follows:

```
NumStep = 0;
Clear[fun];
Clear[func]; 
fun[l1_?NumericQ, l2_?NumericQ, l3_?NumericQ, c12_?NumericQ, 
  d12_?NumericQ, e12_?NumericQ, f12_?NumericQ, g12_?NumericQ, 
  h12_?NumericQ] := 
 Block[{x, y, z}, 
  First[Minimize[{z + 
      l1*(-x*c12 - y*d12 - 
         z - (((c12 - 1)^2 + d12)*(c12 + (2 - d12)))/6) + 
      l2 *(-x*e12 - y*f12 - 
         z - (((e12 - 1)^2 + f12)*(e12 + (2 - f12)))/6) + 
      l3*(-x*g12 - y*h12 - 
         z - (((g12 - 1)^2 + h12)*(g12 + (2 - h12)))/6), -50 <= x <= 
       50 && -50 <= y <= 50 && -50 <= z <= 50}, {x, y, z}]]];
func[c2_?NumericQ, d2_?NumericQ, e2_?NumericQ, f2_?NumericQ, 
   g2_?NumericQ, h2_?NumericQ] :=
  Block[{x1, y1, z1}, 
   First[Maximize[{fun[x1, y1, z1, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2], 
      x1 <= 0 && y1 <= 0 && z1 <= 0}, {x1, y1, z1}]]];
res = Maximize[{func[c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1], 
    0 <= c1 <= 2 && 0 <= d1 <= 2 && 0 <= e1 <= 2 && 0 <= f1 <= 2 && 
     0 <= g1 <= 2 && 0 <= h1 <= 2}, {c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1}] ;
```

But the evaluation stops as soon as it starts. Please explain the error (syntax or logic) that stops the evaluation.

Comment: If you removed the `;` you would notice that the calculation immediately returns unevaluated. Since you care about numerical results, try changing all the `Maximize` to `NMaximize` for a start. It is best to troubleshoot a complex computation piece your piece, so make sure that each of your functions evaluates correctly when you feed it some numerical input before you blindly go for the final result.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions. Individually the function evaluations are returning values, but combining them is not working. Is there any limit to nesting the optimization functions?